# Backbone collection adding item on update and showing it in view

Tags: javascript, session, backbone.js

lots of almost same questions here but not quite what I'm looking for. I need help in creating self-updating session list which receives new session from socket and puts it into the session view. First problem is already when receiving the session. Here is the code:

```
var SessionsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Session,

initialize: function() {
var self = this;
this.socket = Socket.connection;

this.socket.on('session update', function(session) {
  if (!self.some(function(sess, index) {
    if (sess.get('_id') === session._id) {
      //If same id, same session which leads to decision - delete or update
      if (session.users.length || session.agents.length) {
        //If there is someone on the other side, update it
        self.set(session);
      } else {
        //Else delete it
        self.trigger('else', self.models);
        self.shift(session);  
        console.log("Deleting section of session updates");
      }
      return true;
    }})) {
    self.push(session);
    self.trigger('push', self.models);
    console.log("Adding section of session updates", self);
  }
});
},
```

I get three console logs "Adding section of session updates" when I try to add session, all with different cid (collection id). Any ideas why?

Second question is then how to proceed without rendering the whole view again. I would like to add sessions to table and I use a code like this:

```
var SessionListView = BaseView.extend({
 id: "session-list-view",
 template: require('./session_list_view.tpl'),

initialize: function(options) {
  this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
  this.collection.on('else', this.render, this);
  this.collection.on('push', this.render, this);
}

postRender: function() {
  var self = this;
  var itemEl = this.$('tbody');

 this.collection.each(function(session) {
   var item = new SessionListItemView({
     model: session,
   });
   itemEl.append(item.render().$el);
 });

  },
});
```

While last part is here:

```
var SessionListItemView = BaseView.extend({
  className: 'session-list-item',
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: require('./session_list_item_view.tpl'),
}
```

All the questions I've seen before though, try to add something on the go and don't really receive sessions in this way. Deleting is also something that I try to implement without rendering all sessions but just deleting right one from the view.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part I think this is because of your socket receiving several events.

For the second part I think your approach is quiet ok, don't forget to define the render fucntion in your subview and also its model.

Render your parent view when instantiate for the first by defining a render fucntion then on "push" trigger an update function (what you called postRender) which will only re-render the subview with it's new data.